# Find $G'\left( x\right)$.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Let $$G\left( x\right)=\int_{x}^{2x}{f\left( t\right)dt}$$ Find $G'\left( x\right).$

I tried to divide the integration interval but the subintervals are expressed in terms of $x$.

Comment: Did you try $\displaystyle G(x)=-\int \limits _0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt+\int \limits_0^{2x}f(t)\,\mathrm dt$?

Comment: Hint: there is a very fundamental calculus theorem that should be helpful here.

Comment: Your idea to subdivide the integration interval is correct, as @GitGud suggests. It doesn't matter that the given limits of integration are variable; you may nonetheless subdivide at any constant value in the domain of $f(t)$.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847066/help-using-fundemental-theorem-of-calculus-for-the-first-time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $F(\cdot)$ be an antiderivative of the integrable function $f(\cdot)$ and $f(\cdot)$ is continuous over the interval $[x, 2x]$.
$$
G(x)=\int_{x}^{2x}f(t)dt=F(2x)-F(x),$$

And we have: $F'(x)=f(x).$

Therefore:

$$G'(x)=\left(F(2x)\right)'-F'(x)=2F'(2x)-F'(x)=2f(2x)-f(x).$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the result
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \! f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t=f(b(x))b'(x)-f(a(x))a'(x)
$$
$G'(x)=f(2x)d(2x)-f(x)d(x)=2f(2x)-f(x)$

For a more general result based on similar ideas, please look at the first section of this Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: You don't want `G^'`, you just need `G'`... That will stop the latex error.